# messages.fetch(id) throws Unknown Message even though said message exists

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to implement a leaderboard system on my discord bot.
The way I tried is regularly modifying a specific message to update the score.
The way I access said message is the following :

```ts
//firstLeaderboardChan is the message's channel id
//firstLeaderboardMsg is the message id
//Both are strings

const chan = await m.guild?.channels.fetch(firstLeaderboardChan) as TextChannel
const leaderboardMsg = await chan.messages.fetch(firstLeaderboardMsg)
leaderboardMsg.edit({embeds: [leaderboard]})
```

However, that code fails when fetching the message, throwing the Unknown Message Exception.
The message definitely exists, and I am 100% sure these are the right IDs (I just verified), and it's not something else that is preventing fetch() from working, since I'm fetching another message several lines above. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are the IDs strings or numbers?

Comment: The IDs are strings